# Ask a specific number of turtles to die in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm constructing a model of cockle growth for fisheries. One aspect of cockle biology is predation. I want to ask a specified number of turtles in a patch to die each tick. The Dictionary doesn't really provide the answer and I don't know how to model this. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you want five turtles on each patch to die, then:

```
ask patches [
  let limit count turtles-here
  ask n-of (min 5 limit) turtles-here [
    die
  ]
]
```

The use of `min` is necessary because if I just said `n-of 5 turtles-here`, I would get an error on any patches with fewer than five.

You might also write:

```
ask patches [
  repeat 5 [
    if any? turtles-here [
      ask one-of turtles-here [
        die
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

which amounts to the same thing, but the `n-of` version should run faster.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to kill 'n' turtles (replace 'n' in the code by an integer)

```
to kill-n-turtles
  repeat 'n' [
   ask one-of turtles [die]
  ]
end
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to add any value, compared to my existing answer?

Comment: in fact, it will fail if not sufficient turtles, which Seth's answer dealt with